# Google Maps (flash) - using the MapTypeStyle

Tags: flash, google-maps, google-maps-styling

I want to color or increase the the size of the inland border lines, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the thickness or colour of any lines on the map. You can only alter the visibility, hue colour, saturation, lightness and gamma values of map features - such as roads, water, transit etc.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

If your map is pretty localised in one specific area, you could create your own custom map tiles and use those instead of the ones Google provides. That way you could make the map look however you like.

Lewis

Comment: This is in the right direction, but i need to be able to lay a solid color ontop of the landscape. 
This is still a very good tool, didnt find it before. Thanks lewi-p

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Thanks, now i know